# Paypal adaptive payments php response after complete payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am new working with adaptive payments of Paypal.
I completed payment using adaptive payment API.

On some research I found, to get transaction details IPN has to be implemented.
I have the code for IPN, but how do I get details just after a transaction is completed so that I could add those details in my database?

I have put the return URL to be the IPN code. Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: You could enter IPN callback URL in PayPal settings page. And this listener should confirm payment on your site

Comment: There are actually many ways to get payment details. IPN is the way to get these details posted to you ASYNCHRONOUSLY, ie NOT in the user's flow. To get the details in the user's flow, you should have them in the return values of the API you call to make the payment. (Or if the payment is made while the user is in the PayPal login redirection flow then they can come back as variables in the return to your site.) IPN is *unrelated* to returnURL. Read the PayPal classic integration guide for for IPN works.